# SSL on Direct Admin

Tags: ssl, secure

I have a regular Expression Engine install on an server that uses Direct Admin (DA)

- system
  -- codeignitter
  -- expressionengine
- logs
- pivate_html
- public_ftp
- public_html
  -- .htaccesss
  -- index.php
  -- admin.php
  -- css
  -- js
  -- images
  -- uploads
  -- themes
- stats
- templates

I've installed a SSL certificate. When I force a template to SSL I get a "The requested URL was not found on this server" message. However when I move the index.php to my private_html directory it finds the (SSL) template(s).

If all my site has to be secure I could have lived with that solution and would move the index.php to the private_html folder. The problem however is that I only want part of my site being secure.

How can I arrange this? Or is this a typical DA or hosting provider issue?

Answer (score 1):

Direct Admin isn't really relavent here. I use it but it's works the same as any other control panel or webserver where SSL is concerned.

Firstly I would change the domain in question in DA to have private_html symlinked to public_html. The setting is called

"Use a symbolic link from private_html to public_html - allows for same data in http and https"

You can find it in the settings for that domain.

This doesn't secure the entire domain, just makes SSL available.

Next you want to force SSL on pages that you want to secure. This can be done with .htaccess for example, although I've never had much luck with that due to the vast amounts of rewrite rules I use for my sites.

I use Force SSL, you will find it on Devot:EE. Works quite well, I just pop a tag in the pages I want SSL

Comment: Spend literally hours to figure this one out. The DA setting: "Use a symbolic link from private_html to public_html - allows for same data in http and https" did the trick.

Comment: Glad that worked for you Robbie. When you first have to get your head around it, it's confusing to say the least. But should all fall into place on any in the future. I'm pretty sure most control panels work the same way too, giving you the option to symlink private_html so this answer should translate to most other panels.